# Выравнивание по центру сразу нескольких параграфов

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста со следующей проблемой.

Есть несколько параграфов без заданной ширины. 
Ранее, чтобы их вместе в виде блока выравнять по центру, я обрамлял их в таблицу с параметром `align="center"`.

Т.к. это больше не валидно, ищу альтернативу на CSS, но пока безрезультатно.

**Главная задача:** нужно среди нескольких параграфов, имеющих свои собственные стили (но все без указания ширины) выбрать самый длинный по ширине, и выровнять по центру исходя из ширины самого длинного (ширина самого длинного из них и должна быть шириной блока, который включает эти параграфы).

В общем, нужно имитировать то, что раньше делал `table align="center"` на современный лад.

Измерить ширину вручную, и указать её, не предлагать, т.к. таких таблиц, которые нужно переделать - тысячи, все с разной шириной. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

```css
.regular {
  margin-top: 0cm;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 30pt;
  margin: 0cm;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: veranda, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p class="regular">Строка 1</p>
  <p class="regular">Строка 2, большей ширины</p>
  <p class="regular">Строка 3</p>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы `div` принял ширину, равную, в данном случае, ширине текста в строке **2** (самой широкой, из трех) и выровнялся по центру.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы Вы предоставили фрагмент года, а лучше если вы предоставите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы можно было лучше понять, как именно у вас построена верстка страницы.

Comment: А зачем вам альтернатива CSS? На CSS многие современные фреймворки построены, к примеру те же bootstrap и materializeCSS. Можно это сделать средствами JavaScript, но зачем? CSS достаточно мощная штука, если им умело пользоваться.

Comment: Присоединяюсь, код + скриншот крайне полезен.

Comment: так? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vbbz7q7L/

Comment: Добавил код. Может ответ и на поверхности, но я пока не могу понять где. Обычно любую задачу с CSS с помощью гугла в течение максимум часа можно решить, но на решение этой задачи потратил уже достаточно много времени, потому решил обратиться за помощью.

Знания CSS у меня на уровне учебника по CSS для начинающих :)

Comment: soledar10, спасибо большое! То, что нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;   
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.regular {
  text-align: center;  
  margin: 0cm;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: veranda, helvetica, sans-serif;       
 }
```

```html
 <div class="center">
    <p class="regular">Строка 1</p>
    <p class="regular">Строка 2, большей ширины</p>
    <p class="regular">Строка 3</p>
  </div>
```

Вариант 2

```css
.center {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.regular {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0cm;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: veranda, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p class="regular">Строка 1</p>
  <p class="regular">Строка 2, большей ширины</p>
  <p class="regular">Строка 3</p>
</div>
```